# How do I read text chunks quicker with libpng?

Tags: c++, node.js, c, libpng

With *libpng*, I’m trying to extract text chunks in a 44-megabyte PNG image (and preferably validate that the PNG data is not malformed (e. g. lacking `IEND`, etc.)). I could do that with `png_read_png` and `png_get_text`, but it took way too long for me, 0.47 seconds, which I’m pretty sure is because of the massive amount of the `IDAT` chunks the image has. How do I do this in a quicker manner?

---

I didn’t need the pixels, so I tried to make libpng ignore the `IDAT` chunks.

#### To have libpng ignore `IDAT` chunks, I tried:

1. `png_read_info(p_png, p_png_information); png_read_image(p_png, nullptr); png_read_end(p_png, p_png_information);` to skip `IDAT` chunks; crashed and failed.
2. `png_set_keep_unknown_chunks` to make libpng *unknow* about `IDAT`, and `png_set_read_user_chunk_fn(p_png, nullptr, discard_an_unknown_chunk)` (`discard_an_unknown_chunk` is a function that does `return 1;`) to discard unknown chunks; a weird CRC error occurred on the first `IDAT` chunk and failed.

And failed to do that.

---

### Edit

Running as a Node.js C++ addon, mostly written in C++, on Windows 10, with i9-9900K CPU @ 3.6 GHz and gigabytes of memory.

Read the image file on an SSD with `fs.readFileSync`, a Node.js method returning a `Buffer`, and tossed it to the libpng to process.

Yes, at first, I blamed libpng for the prolonged computation. Now I see there might be other reasons causing the delay. (If that’s the case, this question would be a bad one with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).) Thank you for your comments. I’ll check my code out again more thoroughly.

---

#### Edit 2

With every step for feeding the PNG data input to the C++ addon kept the same, I ended up manually picking and decoding text chunks only, with my C pointer magic and some C++ magic. And, the performance was impressive (0.0020829 seconds on processing), being almost immediate. Don’t know why and how though.

```
B:\__A2MSUB\image-processing-utility>npm run test

> image-processing-utility@1.0.0 test B:\__A2MSUB\image-processing-utility
> node tests/test.js

----- “read_png_text_chunks (manual decoding, not using libpng.)” -----
[
  {
    type: 'tEXt',
    keyword: 'date:create',
    language_tag: null,
    translated_keyword: null,
    content: '2020-12-13T22:01:22+09:00',
    the_content_is_compressed: false
  },
  {
    type: 'tEXt',
    keyword: 'date:modify',
    language_tag: null,
    translated_keyword: null,
    content: '2020-12-13T21:53:58+09:00',
    the_content_is_compressed: false
  }
]
----- “read_png_text_chunks (manual decoding, not using libpng.)” took 0.013713 seconds.

B:\__A2MSUB\image-processing-utility>
```

Comment: Why don't you run it under a profiler and see where the time is spent, instead of guessing? Libpng is open source and Vtune is free nowadays.

Comment: Maybe you can share the PNG via Dropbox, Google Drive or somesuch? What do you mean exactly by *"preferably validate the PNG data"*? Validate **what**? What are the pixel dimensions and bit-depth/colour_type of this massive file - because a) your disk has to read 44MB which might take 0.3s on a 150MB/s disk and b) you may be allocating GB of memory to expand a compressed PNG into.

Comment: You might also clarify your environment - on a Raspberry Pi Zero with a USB 2.0 Memory Stick 0.47s would be impressive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do something similar, but where I wanted libpng to do all of the metadata chunk parsing (e.g. `eXIf`, `gAMA`, `pHYs`, `zEXt`, `cHRM`, etc. chunks).  Some of these chunks can appear after the `IDAT`, which means the metadata can't be read with just `png_read_info`.  (The only way to get to them would be to do a full decode of the image, which is expensive, and then call `png_read_end`.)

My solution was to create a synthetic PNG byte stream that is fed to libpng via the read callback set using `png_set_read_fn`.  In that callback, I skip all `IDAT` chunks in the source PNG file, and when I get to an `IEND` chunk, I instead emit a zero-length `IDAT` chunk.

Now I call `png_read_info`: it parses all of the metadata in all of the chunks it sees, stopping at the first `IDAT`, which in my synthetic PNG stream is really the end of the source PNG image.  Now I have all of the metadata and can query libpng for it via the `png_get_xxx` functions.

The read callback that creates the synthetic PNG stream is a little complicated due to it being called by libpng multiple times, each for small sections of the stream.  I solved that using a simple state machine that processes the source PNG progressively, producing the synthetic PNG stream on-the-fly.  You could avoid those complexities if you produce the synthetic PNG stream up-front in memory before calling `png_read_info`: without any real `IDAT`s, your full synthetic PNG stream is bound to be small...

While I don't have benchmarks to share here, the final solution is fast because `IDAT`s are skipped entirely and not decoded.  (I use a file seek to skip each `IDAT` in the source PNG after reading the 32-bit chunk length.)

Comment: What a clever approach that is only with libpng!

Answer (score 1):

You can check that all the correct PNG chunks are in a file, in the correct order, and not repeated and with correct checksums using [pngcheck](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html). It is open source so you could look at how it works.

If you add the parameter `-7`, you can not only check the structure but also extract the text:

```
pngcheck -7 a.png
```

**Output**

```
File: a.png (60041572 bytes)
date:create:
    2020-12-24T13:22:41+00:00
date:modify:
    2020-12-24T13:22:41+00:00
OK: a.png (10000x1000, 48-bit RGB, non-interlaced, -0.1%).
```

I generated a 60MB PNG and the above check takes 0.067s on my MacBook Pro.